# how to deploy artifacts (jar files) from POM.xml into jFrog repository?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am new to this repository world.
I have a maven project i.e MavenExample from GitHub. and I have installed a jFrog artifactory in my machine.

My Aim is to deploy all the jar files listed in my pom.xml into jFrog artifactory instead of .m2 repo (default). This deployment of jar file must ocucur after mvn deploy command.

I have tried adding distributionManagement inside Pom.xml and changing the settings.xml inside maven/conf.

Can someone help... much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

You can try editing "localRepository" in your settings.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<!-- localRepository
| The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
|
| Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
-->

<!--
REST OF THE CODE 
-->
</settings>
```

Go to your project directory and launch "mvn deploy".

Comment: Manually it's fine but what my need is to resolve the dependency in POM directly into artifactory's repository instead of resolving inside .M2 repository.

Comment: Can you attach your settings.xml?

Comment: @Amit Check my response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain this information is from the "Set Me Up" section of Artifactory. Select the repository in the Artifacts tab, and in the top right corner, click "Set Me Up". Assuming you are using a local repository for deploying (remote will not work for deploying, only for resolving dependencies), it will show a section for deploying which will include the distribution management section. Place this in the pom.xml file of the parent project and this running the mvn deploy command from this directory will deploy to Artifactory.

A great way to see a working example of this is to view the "maven-example" section in [JFrog's public Github page](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples) . You can see the parent project has 3 sub-modules (multi1, multi2, and multi3). Adding the distribution management section mentioned previously to the parent pom.xml file and then running mvn deploy from the parent project's root directory will deploy all the binaries to Artifactory.

If for some reason this is still not working, please provide your pom.xml for the parent, the name, package type, and if it is a local/remote/virtual of the repository. Additionally, please provide any output of the mvn deploy command (with the -X option) and anything you can find in the artifactory.log and request.log files ($ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log and request.log)